# Изменение данных в потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Начал изучать MVVM и столкнулся с недопониманием. Например чтобы записать данные из ViewModel во View , необходимо их заполнить в конструкторе ViewModel(). А если мне необходимо в потоке изменять данные и чтобы они изменялись во View. Попытался сделать чтобы делегат транслировал в отдельном потоке, но данные не изменяются.

View

```
<Window x:Class="information_system_wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Normal" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="RunningLine">   
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Right)" From="525" To="-150" 
                                                     Duration="0:0:01" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid Background="White" DataContext="{Binding Models}">

            <Canvas >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RunLine, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Style="{StaticResource RunningLine}"/>
            </Canvas>        
    </Grid>



</Window>
```

Command

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace information_system_wpf
{
    class Command : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public Command(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace information_system_wpf
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
        public Model Models { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {



        }

        private Command addCommand;

        public Command AddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return addCommand ?? (addCommand = new Command(obj =>
                {
        //Phone phone = new Phone();
        //Phones.Insert(0, phone);
        // SelectedPhone = phone;
                }));
            }
            set 
            {
                addCommand = value;
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }


    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace information_system_wpf
{
    class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string runline;

        public string RunLine
        {
            get { return runline; }
            set
            {
                runline = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RunLine");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Где тут работа с потоками? Если вы что то меняете в интерфейсе и оно не меняется во ViewModel или что то меняете во ViewModel и оно не меняется на UI, то, в первую очередь, проверяйте биндинги

Comment: У вас есть три слоя: M, VM и V. Между какими слоями нету соответствия? Данные в VM не соответствуют данным в M, или отображение в V не соответствует данным в VM?

Comment: Да, и вы привязываетесь к модельным объектам. Так нельзя, например, потому, что модельный объект имеет право жить в своём потоке. Привязывайтесь к VM-объектам.

Comment: @tym32167 У меня это работает, я говорю в ViewModel в конструкторе, просто заполняю объект и выводится в UI. А мне нужно чтобы поток считывал допустим обновления UI из базы свойства изменялись и UI обновлялся. Я попробовал транслировать данные через делегат, в отдельном потоке, но окно подвисает, пока не дойдет до последнего изменения.

Comment: @VladD я имел ввиду, уже данные например привязал и при считывании новых, чтобы они обновлялись. Я делал в отдельном потоке через делегатов в ViewModel, но все равно подвисало, пока до последнего элемента не считается.

Comment: Все равно не очень понятно. Может покажете, что вы пробовали? Если дело в обновлении данных - используйте ```public ObservableCollection<Model> Models```, а данные считывайте  из БД асинхронно (или просто создайте для этого поток). Я, к примеру, в своем приложении использовал SQL Compact, который не поддерживает асинхронное чтение, потому я просто в таске запускал https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/develop/src/Arma3BE.Client.Libs/Repositories/ChatRepository.cs#L16

Comment: @Идентикон: Ну, то, что вы делали и оно как-то работало, вовсе не означает, что вы делали правильно, и что оно и дальше будет работать. И я вам уже озвучил причину, по которой не стоит привязываться к модельным данным (кроме очевидного нарушения паттерна MVVM).